# Moving a Function Website: Now CSS fails when loaded locally, succeeds when loaded remotely

Tags: css, apache2

I'm moving a record keeping utility from a remote host to a machine in house. Turns out the user-facing aspects are less appealing than we anticipated, so we're discontinuing them and running the thing on the local network instead.

Everything seems to be in order with one exception; CSS loaded from a CDN (or any remote source) is applied. CSS loaded from a local file is not.

Chrome developer tool indicates that the file is being loaded correctly; it's formatting is simply not being applied.

There have been no code changes from the functioning site on the remote server, which leads me to the conclusion that the problem is environmental. I'm using the same LAMP stack as we were on the remote host, but I have a sneaking suspicion that there's a switch I've forgotten to flip in apache2 somewhere.

Copying the site directly from the remote host results in the same problem. I can make the CSS apply correctly if I modify the loading link to point to the exact same CSS file *anywhere that is not local to the hosting machine*, but if it's loading from the host itself, it's simply not applied.

I've been banging my head on this for three days now, and I just *know* it's going to be something simple that I overlooked while setting up the webserver. Thank you in advance for your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue goes away when I run sample basic html with sample basic CSS. There's apparently a lot more going on here than a simple server configuration issue, so this question doesn't really address the problem anymore.

This question should be closed out.